# Why visual studio 2012 does not install in windows xp?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-xp, compatibility

I have tried to install the visual studio 2012 on windows XP.It does not get installed. Then I searched it for OS compatibility. There I have found that there is no support for windows XP. What is the reason?

Comment: XP is 10 years old, they can't keep supporting everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Microsoft decided not to support Windows XP.